# Facebook SSO for Outlook Add-In on Windows 7

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-7, outlook, single-sign-on

I have an Outlook Add-In and I want to authenticate the users using Facebook SSO for some of my work. I seen  some SDKs like http://facebooksdk.net, but they have explained using WebAuthenticationBroker which is supported on Windows 8. Is there a good resource/sample examples to implement it on Windows 7 for an Outlook Add-In?

Thanks in advance.
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

I suppose all SDK are based on the REST API and don't depend on the OS version. Also you need to consider an Outlook add-in as a regular .Net applicaton. As for the sample, see the [sample code](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample) on GitHub.

Finally, you may find the [Facebook Authentication with the Facebook C# SDK and ASP.NET MVC 4](https://ntotten.com/2012/12/19/facebook-authentication-with-the-facebook-c-sdk-and-asp-net-mvc-4/) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your reply. Now I am using the same Facebook SDK for .NET (http://facebooksdk.net/). I found this blog very helpful: http://blog.prabir.me/posts/facebook-csharp-sdk-writing-your-first-facebook-application-v6